# Seleção de um valor Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Olá, bom dia,

Gostaria de pedir ajuda, por gentileza, em um problema de seleção de tabela.

Gostaria de acessar o valor numérico da variável Peso Relativo da linha selecionada.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np Peso = input ('Qual seu peso considerando a gravidade do planeta terra : ')
planetas = {'Planeta': ['Mercúrio', 'Vênus', 'Terra', 'Marte', 'Júpiter', 'Saturno','Urano','Netuno'], 
                     'Pesorelativo': [0.38,0.91,1,0.38,2.34,1.06,0.92,1.19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(planetas)
PesoRel = input('Em qual planela se encontra: ')

df_mask=df['Planeta']==PesoRel
filtered_df = df[df_mask]
print(filtered_df)
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usa essa linha de código:

```
filtered_df.iloc[0]['Pesorelativo']
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado Rafael Chaves, sou muito grato pela ajuda